# Java program on Win7/AMD

Tags: java, windows, x86-64

I have a Java program that does several file I/O. Runs fine and get compiled on X86/Win7-64b. The exactly .jar is copied to an AMD/Win7-64b and does strange things like cannot open streams or does'nt read till end.

Could there be any issue in Java execution when running on the same OS but diferent procesor architectures ?

Both has Java Version  1.7.0_09

For the records:

The problem was a slightly different  DLL in the 2 Win7 installations that uses a JNI bridge in my program.

Comment: Can you give us more information about the strange things ? Like a stack trace or error message.

Comment: Just for reference, I routinely compile Java apps on AMD and run them on both AMD and Intel without any problems.  I'm also using Java 7U9.  We don't do a lot of stream operations, but the ones we do work fine.

Comment: There are no errors at all. It does'nt do on AMD what it does on X86 (it's all a guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is, you can easily figure it out on your own.  Just be aware of the following things when you launch your program:

1. Are you executing java from the 64-bit cmd.exe shell or the 32-bit SYSWOW cmd.exe shell?
2. Is your JAVA_HOME pointing to a 32bit or 64bit java?
3. Your PATH should be set to PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

If that doesn't clue you in, then it could just be a problem with closing your streams or something.   I heard that the File-IO libraries changed in JDK1.7 ... are you using that newer syntax or are you still reading files using the older JDK1.6 traditions?

Comment: It points all to 32bit. Good old java.io. The cmd.exe could be a point, because it is a standalone that runs from a run.bat script.

Comment: Using the variable "%ProgramFiles%" you can make your .bat script force the user to run it from a 32-bit shell.

Comment: The problem was a slightly different DLL in the 2 Win7 installations that uses a JNI bridge in my program.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. What did you have set for your java library path?